# how to pass the map from one method to onother method

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I have trigger after insert and after update

```
if(trigger.isinsert){
Forecastcheckemail fr=new Forecastcheckemail(trigger.newmap,null);
fr.SendEmail();
}
If(trigger.Isupdate)
{
Forecastcheckemail fr=new Forecastcheckemail(trigger.newmap,trigger.oldmap);
fr.SendEmail();
}
```

Apex Class:

[image]

I want **newOppMap** in sendEmail() Method as well.
But i am getting error  in the line   **Opportunity opp = newOppMap.get(id);**.....Please suggest

Comment: Please stop using the SFDC and Salesforce-crm tags - this site is Salesforce StackExchange so all questions are about Salesforce here and those tags are redundant.

Comment: is it still open?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass the new map in `fr.SendEmail();` method

```
fr.SendEmail(Trigger.NewMap);
```

and your method will be

```
public void SendEmail(map<Id, Opportunity>){

}
```

Or Another way use a private map in the controller to store the new map and old map and when you controller constructor called. Just assign the old and new map to private variables and use those variables in wherever you want